# Validity of proofs containing their own definitions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, definition

While self-studying, I came across the following practice problem:

"Decide the validity of the following and provide a proof.  Two real numbers satisfy $a \lt b \iff a \lt b + \epsilon$  for every $\epsilon \gt 0$"

While it seems obvious that this is the case based on my intuitive understanding of addition, I'm confused about how to formally prove this in a non-trivial way given that the statement seems to be defining the relation "is less than", but then goes on to use that same relation in its own definition.  Is a self-referential definition like this valid, or am I completely misunderstanding what the problem is asking?

The best I could think of was something along the lines of

Assume $\exists \epsilon \gt 0 : a \geq b + \epsilon$ 
Then $a - \epsilon \geq b$ 
And $a - \epsilon \geq a$ 
So by contradiction, $a \lt b+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon \gt 0$

Comment: " $a \lt b \iff a \lt b + \epsilon$ for every $ \epsilon >0$ " is false !

For example we have $0 \lt 0 + \epsilon$ for every $ \epsilon >0$ , but $0 <0$ is not true.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The less-than relation has presumably been defined or characterized for real numbers by the time this problem arises, so there is no self-referential definition in the problem. The question implicitly has two parts: (i) If $a < b$, then $a < b+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$; (ii) If $a < b+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, then $a < b$. <> As Fred notes, the second requires more thought if intuition says both implications are true.